# Typescript rest parameter with two possible array types

Tags: typescript, overloading

I would like to define a function with a rest parameter of either strings or objects, signature like:

```
public static fn(...messages: string[] | object[]): void;
```

But unfortunately this results in a `TS2370` compile error

> error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.

I know having a single type of array like `string[]` or `object[]` works fine, but then overloading such function comes with even greater price.

Is there anyway I could make the mentioned function working with the desired signature?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple types for your rest parameter. However, you must declare it as a single array type:

```
declare function fn(...messages: (string | object)[]): void;

// or with custom type:
// type MessageType = string | object;
// declare function fn(...messages: MessageType[]): void;

fn('aaa', { });
```

Otherwise you are saying it can accept an array of strings or an array of objects, however it only accepts `1 typed array` (combining string and object makes it 1 type).